# Getting a line with a lot of empty spaces

Tags: java, sockets, io, udp

I made a program to send a data to a client through UDP, but I am getting a line with a lot of empty spaces for some reason

Example:

line1: William Shakespeare 3432 Green Street Greenville 450-122-3435

line2:

Do you know why I am getting those? Something tells me it has to do with **buffer.length**, but I am not sure.

```
    DatagramSocket socket1 = new DatagramSocket();
    InetAddress IP1 = msg.getAddress();
    int port = msg.getPort();

    Set set = (obj.getMAP()).entrySet();
    Iterator i = set.iterator();
    String total = "";

    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Person>> me = (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Person>>)i.next();
        Iterator<Account> it = (me.getValue()).iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Account per = it.next();
            String temp = per.getName() + " " + per.getAddress() + " " + 
                          per.getPhoneNumber() + "\n";                      
            total += temp;
        }
    }       

    byte[] buffer = total.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket reply = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, IP1, port);
    socket1.send(reply);
    socket1.close();
```

Comment: what is gonna go for line 2?

Comment: there is a lot of empty spaces like 100 or something like that. it messes up my entire program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line 2 which you refer to be having empty spaces doesn't really contain empty spaces.
You're getting that extra line because of this:

```
temp = per.getName() + " " + per.getAddress() + " " + per.getPhoneNumber() + "\n";
                                                                               ^
```

What you should do is have a condition to determine if this `Account` is not the last one before appending `\n` to it.

```
temp = per.getName() + " " + per.getAddress() + " " + per.getPhoneNumber();
if(it.hasNext()) {
    temp += "\n";
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Not only I am getting an extra line, but I am also getting an endless amount of trailing white spaces.